# Can you do ROCH and LwIP simulations with OMNET++

Tags: omnet++, lwip

I need to run a simulation making use of the Robust Header Compression (ROCH) and Light Weight IP (LwIP) compression standards. From what I can see it does not look like Omnet++ or INET support these compression standards. (LwIP is currently under construction but not available yet.)
Does this imply that I am going to have to write the implementations by myself or do you have any advice for me, please?

Kind regards
Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any ROCH implementation in INET, so yes. You may have to do your own implementation. As for the LwIP part. LwIP is an actual (lightweight) implementation of the TCP/IP stack. It's not a compression standard and INET *does* work with LwIP just fine (by using the LwIP implementation isntead of its own native one). That feature is present in INET for several years now, but it is disabled by default (though you can easily switch on the feature on the project)

Comment: Hey Rudi.

I am trying to simulate the lwIP example simulation on OMNET 5.6.1. I am using INET 4.2.4. The simulation I am trying to run can be found at inet/examples/inet/nclients/omnetpp.ini When I try to run it, it gives me errors. Also the omnet.ini file contains errors. Do I need to install TCP (NSC) in order to run lwIP simulations?

Thank you in advance. Benjamin

Comment: No lwIP is a completely separate thing to NSC.